# Manually change DateTime asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, calendar

When I see the date coming in from my calendar  asp:calendar  I see that it is

```
Date = {9/25/2015 12:00:00 AM}
```

So setting the datetime like this works

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(Calendar1.SelectedDate).Year, Convert.ToDateTime(Calendar1.SelectedDate).Month, Convert.ToDateTime(Calendar1.SelectedDate).Day);
```

However I have a variable that is a string

```
string myDate = "9/25/2015"
```

I thought that I should be able to do this

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(myDate  + " 12:00:00 AM");
```

That gives error about cannot convert string to long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=VS.110).aspx):

```
string s = "9/25/2015";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the value:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(myDate  + " 12:00:00 AM");
```